# using dll built in another version of visual studio

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have to use a third-party dll in my C++ project. All I know about this dll is that it was built in Visual Studio 2013. I use VS2010 and can not switch to 2013 because reasons.

Said dll exports some functions that return std::string. Unsurprisingly, calling those functions produces an access violation in some string deallocation code.

As far as I understand the problem, that's nothing to be surprised of, also nothing that could be done about other than switching to VS2013, which I can't.

Here is the thing though. This third-party dll comes with a c# example project that imports it and works just fine!

So my questions are:

1. (purely theoretical one) Why? Is it .NET string marshaling magic at work?
2. Suppose I wrap the offending dll in a managed dll of my own, then use that managed wrapper in my unmanaged code. Will it work?
3. If the answer to question 2 is yes, then how? I know literally nothing about c# so i wouldn't mind a few pointers.

EDIT:

So out of pure desperation I tweaked the imported function signature in my project - it was `std::string (__cdecl *TFunc)();`, changed it to `BSTR (__cdecl *TFunc)();` - and it works! even though both library manual and the dependency walker tool insist std::string is correct. Posting this as an edit and not an answer because I still don't know what's going on here and it is scary.

Comment: The rule of thumb with typical C++ implementations is that they tend to be backwards compatible, not forwards compatible. You can generally run code built by an older C++ compiler using runtime libraries from the newer version of the same compiler; but the reverse isn't true. C# is completely irrelevant here, because C# is not C++. There are always individual exceptions, this is only a rule of thumb.

Comment: If the example project works under VS2010 then there's nothing wrong on using it, you must have an error somewhere else.

Comment: It only looks like it works, you in fact leak the memory occupied by the std::string object.  Only correct way to do it is to with a C++/CLI project.  And VS2013.  Use a telephone, ask the author to provide you with the correct build or a more friendly interface that actually returns a BSTR.  Although it is rather doubtful you should trust them to know what they are doing when they gave you a sample C# project.